# PHP preg_split in to array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-split

I'm using `preg_split` to split a value. I need to store each value of the split into an array.

currently what is being passed in to the preg split is:

```
preg_split("/[0-9]/", fujitsu30001 , NULL , PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I need it to split on each number so it appears as:

```
[fujitsu, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

in an array, any help would be great on this matter.

Would it be better to use `preg_match`?

Comment: So you want output to be array containing fujitsu, 30001 only ??

Comment: I assume fujitsu, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1

Comment: Please note that `fujitsu30001` refers to the `CONSTANT` with that name. `'fujitsu30001'` or `"fujitsu30001"` refers to a STRING with that content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_split("/(?=[0-9])/", 'fujitsu30001');
```

http://ideone.com/9H65fW

Answer (score 1):

You should use matching instead of splitting:

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+|\d/i', 'fujitsu30001', $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The expression matches either:

1. a sequence of letters or,
2. a single digit.

This is repeated until it reaches the end of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it via preg_split:

```
$regex= "#([0-9])#";
$string = 'fujitsu30001';                    
$array = preg_split($regex, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

which split the string on hitting a number so it appeared as

fujitsu,
3,
0,
0,
0,
1